# What is led_cdev? And how to use it in Linux kernel (directly)?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to debug a kernel panic on an embedded device with no access to serial output. The device has a small notification LED which is supported by a driver in the Linux kernel.

So, I thought of porting `kernel/morse.c` to Linux's LED subsystem (the original used something related to virtual terminal).

However, I've quickly ran into an issue. See, there is a `led_brightness_set()` function which can be used to turn on/off the LED. It takes two arguments - `led_cdev` (the LED device struct) and `brightness_value` (brightness value).

I know how to set the `brightness_value` but I don't know how to create/get `led_cdev`. Is there a function for this?